# US -> American, Canada -> Canadian, etc

Tags: onomastics

What is the proper onomastic descriptor for words like American, Canadian, etc to describe nouns, like Bank?

For example:

- American Bank
- Canadian Bank
- British Bank
- French Bank
- Japanese Bank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) is a noun identifying a person related to a particular place.

[Ethnonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnonym) is a noun identifying an ethnic group.

"American", "Canadian" in "American bank", "Canadian bank" are simply adjectives, which may be called adjectival forms of place names (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_of_place_names)). Sporadically they are called demonymic adjectives.

In English language, demonyms and demonymic adjectives are often identical, but they are not in many languages:

Demonymic adjective "Ukrainian" in Ukrainian language is [український](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) (ukrajinsʹkyj).

Demonymic adjective "American" in Ukrainian language is [американський](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) (amerykansʹkyj).

Demonym "Ukrainian (person)" in Ukrainian language is [українець](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) (ukrajinecʹ) / [українка](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) (ukrajinka).

Demonym "American (person)" in Ukrainian language is [американець](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) (amerykanecʹ) / [американка](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) (amerykanka).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for; thank you!